# Change layer size to fit non-white region

Tags: gimp

After selecting the region I want to keep, I invert the selection and press delete to remove all the areas I don't want.

Now I'm left with the stuff I want to keep, and a bunch of white where the removed stuff were.  How do I change the layer size so that it tightly fits the region I want to keep, removing the unused white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Layer>Crop to content` removes the largest possible area around the outside edge which all has the same color.

`Image>Crop to content` does the same for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the layer ( background or whatever layer you want) right click and toward the bottom you will see add alpha channel if it is not Greyed out click it. Then go to layers at the top, go down to transparency click color to alpha. That should work. If it doesn’t get fuzzy select tool and try clicking the white area and pressing delete. Hope this helps